# Issues with returning Model with list of Models to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

as in the title I am having issues with returning a model that has a list of models as one of the values. The goal is a page model that contains a few key values along with a user list and report list. but upon return either just the list values are null or the entire model has been remade with default values.

The ReportViewModel:

```cs
namespace DataLibrary.Models
{
    public  class ReportViewModel
    {
        

        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; } = "0";
        public string Admin { get; set; } = "n";
        public List<ReportModel> Reports { get; set; }
        public List<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday));
        public DateTime End { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    }
}
```

With both UserModel and ReportModel having numerous values of string, BitArray, and int. I have created a more simple test view for my troubleshooting below. This is mainly to test just returning the lists as a whole without any editing as it should be easier, which still proves ineffective:

```
@model DataLibrary.Models.ReportViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Report1";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<form asp-action="SelectDate">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row form-group">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Reports"  />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Users" />
            <div class="col-4">
                <input asp-for="@Model.Start"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <input asp-for="@Model.End"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <input type="submit" value="Select Date Range" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
        @if (Model.Admin != "n")
        {

            <div class="row">

                <input asp-for="Admin" hidden="hidden" />

                @{
                    var perm1 = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
            {"id", Model.Id},
            {"adm", Model.Admin}

            };
                }
                <div class="col-4"><a asp-controller="Timesheet" asp-action="AuthAll" asp-all-route-data="perm1" class="btn btn-primary">Authorize All</a></div>



                <div class="col-4">
                    <select asp-for="Id">
                        @for (int e = 0; e < Model.Users.Count; e++)
                        {
                            if (Model.Users[e].USER_ID == Model.Id)
                            {
                                <option value="@Model.Users[e].USER_ID" selected="selected">@Model.Users[e].USER_FIRST_NAME @Model.Users[e].USER_LAST_NAME</option>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <option value="@Model.Users[e].USER_ID">@Model.Users[e].USER_FIRST_NAME @Model.Users[e].USER_LAST_NAME</option>
                            }
                        }
                    </select>

                    <input type="submit" value="Select User" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</form>
```

In the actual view I originally used foreach but saw others saying that was not a good way to go about it and a basic for loop worked better? So I am currently using the bellow as the full view/editing the models inside the report list, but am using the above to troubleshoot the issue of not returning the lists and proper values. Upon submitting the below, the Reports list in the model sent to the controller has the correct number of entries but all values are NULL. This was the case with both the foreach and for loop versions:

```
@model DataLibrary.Models.ReportViewModel

@{
}
<form asp-action="SelectDate">
    <div class="container">
<div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-4">
        <input asp-for="@Model.Start"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
        <input asp-for="@Model.End"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
    <input type="submit" value="Select Date Range" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
</div>
    @if(Model.Admin != "n")
    {
            
        <div class = "row">

            <input asp-for="Admin" hidden="hidden"/>

                @{var perm1 = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                    {"id", Model.Id},
                    {"adm", Model.Admin}

                    };}
            <div class="col-4"><a asp-controller="Timesheet" asp-action="AuthAll" asp-all-route-data="perm1" class="btn btn-primary">Authorize All</a></div>

                
            
            <div class="col-4">
                <select asp-for="Id">
                        @for(int e = 0; e< Model.Users.Count; e++)
                        {
                            if (Model.Users[e].USER_ID == Model.Id)
                            {
                                <option value="@Model.Users[e].USER_ID" selected="selected">@Model.Users[e].USER_FIRST_NAME @Model.Users[e].USER_LAST_NAME</option>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <option value="@Model.Users[e].USER_ID">@Model.Users[e].USER_FIRST_NAME @Model.Users[e].USER_LAST_NAME</option>
                            }
                        }

                   @*  @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
                    {
                        if (user.USER_ID == Model.Id)
                        {
                            <option value="@user.USER_ID" selected="selected">@user.USER_FIRST_NAME @user.USER_LAST_NAME</option>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <option value="@user.USER_ID">@user.USER_FIRST_NAME @user.USER_LAST_NAME</option>
                        }
                    } *@
                </select>
                <!-- send model and select based on values, date, user, etc-->
              
                    <input type="submit" value="Select User" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    </div>
</form>




 <form asp-action="Update">
     <div class="form-group">
<table class="ReportTable " >
    <thead>
        <tr class="ReportRows">
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Date")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Attendance")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Hours")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Over")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Update/Unauth")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Authenticate")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Delete")
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

            <input asp-for="@Model.Start" type="hidden"></input>
            <input asp-for="@Model.End" type="hidden"></input>
        <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Reports" />
            <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Users" />
        @for (int i = 0; i< Model.Reports.Count; i++)
        {
          
            <div class="form-group">
            <tr class="ReportRows">
                    @* <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Reports[i].SALARIED1" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Reports[i].PRESENT1" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Reports[i].PRESENT_AFTERNOON1" /> *@
                <th>
                        @Html.DisplayName(Model.Reports[i].DATE1.ToString())
                </th>
                <th>
                        @if (Model.Reports[i].SALARIED1[0] == true)
                        {
                            //if salaried show am pm
                        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Reports[i].PRESENT1[0]" />
                        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Reports[i].PRESENT_AFTERNOON1[0]" />
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //TimeOnly t = TimeOnly.FromDateTime(entry.CLOCKIN1);

                        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Reports[i].CLOCKIN1" />
                        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Reports[i].CLOCKOUT1" />
                            // if not salaried show times
                        }
                </th>
                <th>

                        @if (Model.Reports[i].SALARIED1[0] == true)
                        {
                            @Html.DisplayName("N/A")
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.DisplayName(Model.Reports[i].totalminute_work1.ToString())
                        }
                </th>
                <th>
                        @if (Model.Reports[i].SALARIED1[0] == true)
                        {
                            @Html.DisplayName("N/A")
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.DisplayName(Model.Reports[i].over_time1.ToString())
                        }
                </th>
                <th>
                        @if (Model.Reports[i].AUTHORIZED1 != null && Model.Reports[i].AUTHORIZED1[0] == true)
                        {
                            // display button to unauth

                            var perm = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                {"Date", Model.Reports[i].DATE1.ToString()},
                {"id", Model.Reports[i].USER_ID1},
                {"tsid", Model.Reports[i].ID1.ToString()},
                {"adm", Model.Admin }

                };
                        <a asp-controller="Timesheet" asp-action="UnAuth" asp-all-route-data="perm" class="btn">UnAuth</a>
                            @*  <a asp-controller="Timesheet" asp-action="Unauth" class="btn">UnAuth</a> *@

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var perm4 = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                {"Date", Model.Reports[i].DATE1.ToString()},
                {"Uname", Model.Reports[i].USER_ID1},
                {"tsid", Model.Reports[i].ID1.ToString()},
                {"adm", Model.Admin } ,
                {"p1", Model.Reports[i].PRESENT1[0].ToString()}
                //,
                //{"p2", Model.Reports[i].PRESENT_AFTERNOON1[0].ToString()}

                };
                            // update times button

                        <a asp-controller="Timesheet" asp-action="Update" asp-all-route-data="perm4" class="btn">Update</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                        }
                </th>
                <th>

                        @if (Model.Reports[i].AUTHORIZED1 != null && Model.Reports[i].AUTHORIZED1[0] == true)
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            var perm = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                {"Date", Model.Reports[i].DATE1.ToString()},
                {"Uname", Model.Reports[i].USER_ID1},
                {"t", null},
                {"adm", Model.Admin }

                };



                        <a asp-controller="Timesheet" asp-action="Auth" asp-all-route-data="perm" class="btn">Auth</a>
                            @* asp - Date = "@entry.DATE1" asp - Uname = "@entry.USER_ID1" asp - t = "" asp - model = "@Model" *@
                            @*  @Html.ActionLink("Auth", "Auth", new{Date = entry.DATE1}, new{Uname = entry.USER_ID1}, new {t = ""}) *@
                        }
                </th>
                <th>
                        @if (Model.Reports[i].AUTHORIZED1 != null && Model.Reports[i].AUTHORIZED1[0] == true)
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var perm3 = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                {"Date", Model.Reports[i].DATE1.ToString()},
                {"Uname", Model.Reports[i].USER_ID1},
                {"tsid", Model.Reports[i].ID1.ToString()},
                {"adm", Model.Admin }

                };
                        <a asp-controller="Timesheet" asp-action="DeleteClock" asp-all-route-data="perm3" class="btn">Delete</a>
                        }
                </th>
            </tr>
            </div>
         
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
</form>
```

The controller parts are pretty simple:

```cs
  public IActionResult Report1()
  {
      if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("User") != null)
      {

          // get info here and pass into view based on session name  
          // need to create option for admins to select different users, and allow all users to select different 
          // date range
          ReportViewModel model = new ReportViewModel();
          List<ReportModel> reports = //redacted database code;

          // session to stand in for validation until I learn that more thoroughly. 
          if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("Admin") != "n")
          {
              entries = _db.user.ToList();
              users = entries.ToList();
          }

          model.Id = HttpContext.Session.GetString("User");
          model.Reports = reports;
          model.Users = users;
          model.Admin = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Admin");
          return View(model);
      }
      else
      {
          return RedirectToAction("Login");
      }
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public IActionResult Report1(ReportViewModel model)
  {
      string test = "";
      return View(model);
  }
```

I apologize as I am still learning a lot about this system, and figured this layout would make for good practice but have hit this roadblock.

as stated above I have attempted to create a simple version of the view to just return the model that is sent in without many changes except for the non list parameters, which still leads to the lists being null. I have attempted setting the name="" attributes on all values to what is listed on the original models, to no avail. I am not sure what is causing the issue of not returning the filled lists at this time. Unfortunately other questions seemed to brush this topic but the one that seemed the closest I could find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48818986/listt-within-the-model-not-reaching-controller-when-form-is-submitted) did not seem to offer any further insight.

Looking at the similar posts it appears I may be missing form-control? I am somewhat burnt out from looking at this so long, so I will return to this later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am having issues with returning a model that has a list of models as
> one of the values. The goal is a page model that contains a few key
> values along with a user list and report list. but upon return either
> just the list values are null or the entire model has been remade with
> default values

Well, based on your scenario and description along with the shared code snippet I have tried to investigate your issue and successfylly reproduced it.

I hope you are getting following null model bindings while submitting the form:

[image]

Investigation Result:

First of all, your submit form and the controller action doesn't have consistencies because its not calling the method you been pointed. So I have fixed that one.

Apart from that, within your code you have tried to bind the model value following this way:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.Reports[i].PRESENT1" />
```

Which actually incorrect and cannot bind the model value accurately while you are submitting the form. Instead you should bind your model within the for loop like below:

For Report model, you should bind he model value this way:

```
 <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Reports[i].Id" />
```

Same goes for User Model as well:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Users[i].USER_ID" />
```

In addition, I noticed, you are binding a select list. In my test I have slidely refactor your code in order to look clean and simpler.

Here is the complete sample I tried the test with:

```
<form asp-action="Update" asp-controller="ModelListTest" method="post">
  
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Reports.Count; i++)
    {
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Reports[i].Id" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Reports[i].Name" />
    }

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Users.Count; i++)
    {
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Users[i].USER_ID" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Users[i].USER_FIRST_NAME" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Users[i].USER_LAST_NAME" />
    }
    <div class="col-4">
        <select asp-for="Id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Users, "USER_ID", "USER_FIRST_NAME"))">
            <option value="">Select User</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Select User" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>

</form>
```

**Note:** Remember, this not the exact solution to your program, I just tried to assist you why you are getting null list value within your controller.

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#collections) in order to achieve detail [insight of model binding.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#collections)

Comment: I thank you for the indepth write up! After goin over it I realized that I am still having an issue of what I thought was the Reports list not going through, but in actuality when I tested this with a user that used CLOCKIN and CLOCKOUT the values were passed properly. 

This has made me realize it was passing back the values, the issue is the BitArrays are having trouble being passed back for some reason it seems. This could be due to having it in ` <input asp-for="@Model.Reports[i].PRESENT1[0]" type="checkbox" />` with the specific cell but not just @Model.Reports[i].PRESENT1?

Comment: Well thanks for your response. The issue seems specific to binding BitArrays, not model binding in general.Binding individual cells of the BitArray (PRESENT1[0]) might be problematic, however, try using `<input asp-for="@Model.Reports[i].PRESENT1" type="checkbox" />` to bind the entire BitArray.
also make sure your model binding configuration supports BitArrays.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. This appears to work for the bitarray, though I moved from BitArray to bool as it is pulling a value from a PostgreSQL database, and I did not realize it could turn bit to bool instead of a BitArray. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm glad to know your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to MVC and it's @Model is that the model *does not* exist in any way shape or form on the client browser. The controller sends the model to the server view engine to compose the HTML to send to the client browser. When the client browser goes to submit a form, MVC's JavaScript goes through the DOM for whatever it can recognize as values that might need to go back to the server. There is no @Model to send back. MVC masks this behaviour to appear like it sends an object model to he client and get that object model back on Submit, except it doesn't actually do that. On a form submit it is passing essentially string values that the server will then attempt to compose a new copy of an object, whether an entity or view model from the various values that get submitted with the POST.

This ultimately means passing complex object graphs back to the server on a form submit gets rather clumsy. In order to pass related objects back to the server, *every* required property on every required related entity needs to have an input control that the submit JavaScript can parse, and that mVC will recognize to be able to re-compose a new, populated copy of that model when it receives all of those fields.  Unfortunately code like this:

```
 <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Reports"  />
```

... isn't enough if you want the reports to go back to the server on POST. You would need to have the page iterate through the @Model.Reports to create hidden inputs for any/all properties you want to send back.

When it comes to using MVC with data like Entity Framework, I don't recommend trying to expect entities to be passed to and from the view, rather look to pass only what the view needs and accept that only the values that the view is editing/referencing will come back, then load the entities on the form Submit to copy relevant updates across after validating. It also helps to plan out update operations to be relatively atomic so changes are applied incrementally rather than in big operations involving a number of changes across a large set of related entities.

Comment: I appreciate the response! 

Yes I am aware that the fields I need returned must have inputs on the page. I explained it in the paragraph after the test code block that I have a for loop going through the fields in the reports class that I need returned but this did not seem to be returning values. 

The 
` <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Reports"  />`
code snippets were added as I was testing to see if because I was returning the properties of the models but not the list of models themselves if that was the issue. 

I do appreciate the insight!